# Как найти сумму случайных чисел (-N,N), сумма которая не была меньше нуля?

Tags: c#, winforms, случайные-числа

Привет! На Form1 поставил label1,textBox1,textBox2,button1 и button2, при нажатий на button1 значения рандом элементов (сколько элементов указываем в textBox1) по таймеру c заданной в textBox2 интервалом генерируется в label1. То есть генерируется на пример 15 чисел в интервале [-8,8], числа могут повторятся и в конце после нажатия button2 получаем сумму. Надо что бы при каждом присвоении чисел, сумма не было меньше 0 (может равняться нулу sum>=0). То есть должна сперва генерироваться положительное число после должно рандомно выходит и положительные и отрицательные числа, но при каждом присвоении их сумма не должна быть меньше 0.

В маем коде иногда первым выходит минус число, и короче как это исправить

```
Timer timer = new Timer();            
Random r = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
int bir = 0, sum = 0;

timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
{
           if (bir == 1) timer.Stop(); 
           int max = sum >= 0 ? 9 - sum : 9;
           var min = sum >= 0 ? -9 : 0;
          var n = r.Next(min, max);
           label1.Text = n.ToString();
           sum += n;
           bir--;
};
button1.Click += (s, e) =>        
{
timer.Start();
timer.Interval = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
bir = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);                
};
button2.Click += (s, e) =>
        {
              label1.Text = sum.ToString();               
        };
```

Comment: Очень сумбурно написано, напишите более конкретно что вам нужно. Вам нужно сгенерировать 2 числа, первое положительное, а второе отрицательное? И чтоб их сумма была положительна?

Comment: Просто нормализуйте набор, если получена отрицательная сумма. В простейшем случае - инкремент случайного не-максимального элемента и повторный контроль суммы... не менее простейший вариант - выбросить любое отрицательное, заменив на случайное неотрицательное. Ещё вариант - просто инвертировать знак всех чисел.

Comment: не ни два а несколько, количество указываю на форме в  textBox1, короче указываю количество и интервал таймера и в  label1 генерируется рандомные числа. Надо найти сумму генерированных чисел. 1+-(1)+3+(-4)+5+6+(-7)+8, но надо чтобы суммы между элементами не было меньше 0. То есть 1+(-1)+4+(-3)+1+0+0

Comment: а как написать в маем коде это? я новичок

Comment: то есть не должно получатся так 1+-(1)+3+(-4)+5+6+(-7)+8, так как тут 3-4= -1, а должно получатся 1+(-1)+4+(-3)+1+0+0 тут сумма 4-3=1 и после идет +1, и в итоге конечная сумма 2

Comment: не знаю как написать это - межсуммы что ли)

Comment: Т.е. вы имеете ввиду то что сумма всех чисел не должна быть меньше 0, так?

Comment: да, генерируется положительное число после любое число но так что бы сумма не было меньше нуля, потом след. число и сумма так же

Comment: Кто ни будь может помочь с этим или это задача невыполнимо?